# How to prevent mysql from adding 2 values with each other in php?

Tags: php, mysql

So i want to add some info to the existing info in mysql, so i use this kind of code:

```
SET date = $alp + number
WHERE id=15 ');
$ES->execute();
$ES->close();
```

here i got 2 little problems:
When i type an integer, it adds them together. Date is preset as an integer, and i type $alp as 3 for example.
Instead of showing 3 4, it shows like 7. It adds 2 numbers. How do i prevent that? I just want them to stay side by side. Anohter problem when i try to put string, that is kind of fair because letter plus number doesnt work. But how do i make the command so the sql gets it as putting it together and not adding them (doing math i mean). would appriciate answers!

Comment: you can ignore that i left out prepare and connect variable btw

Comment: If date is of type int you cant just save 2 numbers (3 4) speareated by whistspace. If you want to save your 2 numbers separated by whitespace you need to save them as a string / text / char or something comparable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CONCAT` to "string" the number together in MySQL..  Like so:

```
SET date = CONCAT($alp, ' number')
```

Your output will be `3 4`

And to concatenate a string in php you would do something like:

```
$alp = '3';
$alp .= ' 4';
echo $alp;
//  output: 3 4
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)